# Issue with conflict in Gemfile when using spree_active_sale and spree 2-2-stable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, e-commerce, spree

I added spree_active_sale but got error in

> Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "spree_core":
>     In Gemfile:
>       spree_active_sale (~> 2.0.0) ruby depends on
>         spree_core (~> 2.0.0) ruby
>   spree (>= 0) ruby depends on
>         spree_core (2.2.2.beta)

**My gem file**

```
gem 'rails', '4.0.4'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'spree', github: 'spree/spree', branch: '2-2-stable'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', github: 'spree/spree_auth_devise', branch: '2-2-stable'
gem 'spree_active_sale' , :git => 'git://github.com/suryart/spree_active_sale.git', :branch => '2-0-stable'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[spree_active_sale's gemspec](https://github.com/suryart/spree_active_sale/blob/master/spree_active_sale.gemspec) says it needs spree '~> 2.0.0'.  Unless they update, or you fix it, you're stuck.

If your project allows it, it seems like you could downgrade spree to 2.0 as well.